# Set default value in material ui dropdown

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm having doubts in material ui dropdown.
This is my doubt.
Initially In material ui dropdown the default value wil be "Select" but while clicking on the dropdown select will not show in the dropdown options. Meaning "Select" is a default value or a placeholder but select is not an option.
How do i achive this?

```
<FormControl>
  <Select 
   Value={props.value} > 
      {props.option.map(option => ( 
     <MeuItem key= {option.value} value={option.value}> 
      {option.label} 
     <MenuItem>))}
 </Select>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far, kindly show some code snippets etc?

Comment: in these examples you can see that 'none' is the default value and can be selected: https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#select - 4th example in the top row

Comment: @JakeB.In that None is showing in the option list. In my case None will not be show in options list , it will like a placehoder. Please suggest me for this

Comment: Yeah, it will a placeholder, will not show in the option list

Comment: @JeevaRekha what do you want? The link Jake has shared in that the first dropdown doesn't have any default value except the placeholder. Other have none as default option.  So I am confused what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to show "Select" in the drop down as a placeholder, but this "select " would not display in the option list of the dropdown.

Comment: Jake has shared a link. In that "None" is showing the option list. My case "None" will not show in the dropdown, it will act like a placeholder

Comment: @JeevaRekha Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: Yes I fixed it, There is a "renderValue" property in dropdown, I used it and fixed the problem

Comment: @JeevaRekha how did you use "Rendervalue"? mind sharing?